# MonoTouch can't open new window from AccessoryButtonTapped

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How do I open an new window from AccessoryButtonTapped button from my BasisViewController. Right now I have this for open, but the problem is the NavigationController which I can't find because I'm inherent the UITableViewSource.

```
Opskrift ops = new Opskrift(item.ImageName, item.Name, item.optionTxt, item.SubHeading)
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.opskrift, true);
```

If I use `ops.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.opskrift, true);`

I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your UITableViewSource inherited class access to your controller by passing it through its constructor:

```
public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{

    private BasisViewController controller;
    public MyTableSource(BasisViewController parentController)
    {
        this.controller = parentController;
    }

    //use like this in a method:
    //this.controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(opskrift, true);
}
```

Your Opfskrift controller's NavigationController property returns null because it is not part of a navigation controller's stack when you initialize it (=hasn't been "pushed" in a navigation controller). Of course, BasisViewController must also belong to a navigation controller for its NavigationController property to contain something other than null.

Comment: I'm getting an error:  Example_CustomUITableViewCells.MyTableSource' does not implement inherited abstract member `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewSource.RowsInSection(MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView, int)'
Example_CustomUITableViewCells.MyTableSource' does not implement inherited abstract member `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewSource.GetCell(MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath)'
 Should i jut implement them and return some null value.

Comment: These two methods are required so that your table view can create the list of items to show. If you return null from GetCell and 0 from RowsInSection, you will have no items shown in the table view.